# crash chrome broswer

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome

i when by "google-chrome-stable" in terminal get error :

```
engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$ google-chrome-stable
[1:1:0617/150719:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[7710:7710:0617/150719:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(201)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Aborted (core dumped)
engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$ ../../sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/sigsys_handlers.cc:**CRASHING**:seccomp-bpf failure in syscall 0221
```

and ouput install gdk module:

```
engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$ sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
[sudo] password for engmmrj: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcanberra-gtk-module is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatspi2.0-0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386
  libcolord1:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libkeybinder0
  liblcms2-2:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386
  libxkbcommon0:i386 linux-headers-3.16.0-30 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$
```

Comment: From where did you install google chrome? If you try installing the packages `libexif*` and `gtk2-engines-murrine` it might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have installed 32bit `google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb` package on 64bit system . uninstall this package and download 64bit package from [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)
and install it . 
you can follow steps explained in my another answer  [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/678463/432559)