# google chrome is not working

Tags: google-chrome

installed Google chrome on my laptop. when i try to launch it nothing happens.
When i run the command

```
google-chrome
```

i get following output,

```
[1:1:0925/232308:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
[8408:8408:0925/232308:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Aborted (core dumped)
```

please help.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If any of the answers solve your problem, please select the best one as accepted. You may vote up every good answer too, after getting enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem some time occurs when you have not installed `google-chrome` package of proper architecture ( when install `32bit` package on `64bit` machine). then it require some packages like `overlay-scrollbar-gtk2` , `unity-gtk2-module`,`libcanberra-gtk-module:i386` etc. so, either install these packages or uninstall google-chrome and reinstall proper architecture packages.
after uninstall `google-chrome` install it again using following steps:

download correct packages from [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html)
install it using command

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

if it fail then install dependencies by running command then install again.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

now run command on terminal

```
google-chrome
```

or

```
google-chrome-stable
```

i have tested it by installing on ubuntu 14.04.